# Subir imagenes con AJAX ERORR

Tags: php, ajax

Hola buenos dias gente tengo un problema con el code ajax para subir imagenes pero no se donde esta error el PHP esta bien porque ya lo probé me pueden decir donde esta Gracias,

**index.php con el code ajax :**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function upload_img(){

    var formData = new FormData($("#formUpload")[0]);
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'upload.php',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
    });

}
</script>

<form onsubmit="return false" class="oculto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUpload">
    <input type="file" name="photoimg" onchange="upload_img();">
</form>
```

**upload.php el code para subir:**

```
<?php
include('db.php');
include('alphaID.php');
session_start();
$session_id='1'; //$user id
$path = "uploads/";
//$uid = "uploads/";


$valid_formats = array("png", "PNG");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
   $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
   $type = $_FILES['photoimg']['type'];
   $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
   if(strlen($name)) {
       $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); 
       $name = alphaID(microtime(true) * 10000);
       if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)) {
       if($size<(50024*50024)) {
          $actual_image_name = $name;
          $video_ext=$ext;
           $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
           if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name.'.'.$video_ext)) {
              shell_exec("ffmpeg -i uploads/".$actual_image_name.".flv -f flv -s 650x390 uploads/".$actual_image_name.".mp4");
              shell_exec("ffmpeg -i uploads/".$actual_image_name.".mp4 -vcodec png -ss 00:00:15 -s 650x390 -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo uploads/".$actual_image_name.".png");

              $newdata=$actual_image_name;
              if($newdata) {
                 echo '<img src="uploads/'.$actual_image_name.'.png" width="100%" height="auto" class="preview_img" />';
              }
            } else {
                echo "Fail upload folder with read access.";
            }
         } else
            echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
         } else
            echo "Invalid file format.";    
     } else
        echo "Please select image..!";
     exit;
  }
?>
```

Comment: ya viste si se envía la data? Revisa en la parte de "Networks" en Developer Tools -> F12 en Firefox, Chrome, IE, Edge.

Comment: no se envía en que ¿falle?

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes esto: onsubmit="return false" ?

Comment: para que no se envie lo dato vacios has esta que selecione una imagen

Comment: sólo por curiosidad, intenta quitarlo

Comment: Has probado en añadir también `cache: false,` en tu `AJAX`?

Comment: ya lo hice y no funciona sigue igual

Comment: Y cuando dices "el PHP esta bien porque ya lo probé" significa que probaste enviando el archivo de la manera tradicional? ¿Comprobaste que del lado del servidor no se recibe nada en el ajax? ¿Puedes dumpear el contenido de $_FILES antes de verificar si $_POST está definido?

Comment: @amenadiel asi es  lo probé como en los viejos tiempo por eso digo que esta bien pero el Ajax esta mal pero no se porque

Comment: una vez que selecciones una archivo, dale un console.log(formData); para ver qué tienes ahí

Comment: no me dice nada de datos solo esto  `FormData {}`

Comment: Es normal que veas eso porque FormData no es un objeto normal. Puedes ver si el objeto tiene valores por medio de un iterador: `let it = formData.entries();
let entry;

while(!(entry = it.next()).done) {
  console.log(entry);
}`. Así sabrás si el FormData tiene contenido, lo cual no veo por qué no lo tuviese.

Answer (score 0):

Me da la impresión de que adosar la función `upload_img` al evento change del input file no es la manera correcta. Yo lo haría así:

```
<form onsubmit="upload_img();" class="oculto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUpload">
    <input type="file" name="photoimg" >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Y me preocuparía de retornar `false` al final de `upload_img`.

Comment: no ni asi funciona